# Can’t find SSD on USB boot Ubuntu

Tags: lenovo

I botched an install of Ubuntu and now I deleted my main partition and have an empty disk.

I have a USB bootable Ubuntu and would like to install it on my main SSD. However the main SSD drive can not be found. When I try and install and choose the drive, there is none to choose from.

Please can someone guide me as to how to fix this error. Even in BIOS it doesn’t show the disk.

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad 320S.

Thank you
Laurence

Comment: First the SSD should be shown in BIOS. Check for this.

Comment: As above or try `sudo fdisk -lu` or `sudo lshw -class disk` to see the output

Comment: @Laurence Hammond at the first line of your question you mentioned "I deleted my main partition and have an emtpy disk" is it the same as "main SSD"?? or you removed the HDD which came when you bought the laptop and replaced it with SSD??

Comment: @Laurence Hammond, Can you check your BIOS Version if it is not the latest one, update it. as per the model number you provided here are some details about latest version BIOS update "Summary of Changes
Latest Version BIOS fixed all merged issues from previous. Version: 4QCN43WW(V2.07) [Added]
Add PCIE SSD RxEQ for "HFS256GD9TNG-62A0A".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The SSD was completely bust. had to replace it